# How to disable controls inside a <TD> for FF and Chrome. IE ok

Tags: css, html-table, disabled-control

I have a few checkbox controls inside a `<td>` that I need to disable so users cannot check the checkboxes.

This all works in IE8 and above, but FF or Chrome, the disable="disabled" is ignored. Why and how can I get around this please?

```
    <td id="tdDocs" runat="server" style="table-layout: fixed; visibility: visible; overflow: auto; border-collapse: separate; font-size: 12pt; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; background-color: transparent; width: 799px; background-image: none;" colspan="2">
        <strong>What documents will be required for today's tasks?<br /></strong>
            <span style="font-size: 9pt">(Please ensure supporting documentation is attached)</span>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator12" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage='Tick one of the "Documents required today" section tick boxes.' OnServerValidate="CustomValidator12_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt">*</asp:CustomValidator><br />
            <table style="width: 651px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; height: 22px; font-weight: bold; width: 247px;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkJSEA" runat="server" Text="JSEA" Width="200px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></strong></td>
                    <td style="height: 22px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; width: 278px; font-family: Arial;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkRISKA" runat="server" Text="Risk Assessment" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></td>
                    <td style="height: 22px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; width: 121px; font-family: Arial;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkWMS" runat="server" Text="Work Method Statement" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 12pt; width: 247px; font-family: Arial; height: 22px;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSOP" runat="server" Text="Safe Operating Procedures" Width="200px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></strong></td>
                    <td style="height: 22px" colspan="2">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkOTHER" runat="server" Text="Other" OnCheckedChanged="chkOTHER_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </td>
```

In code-behind, I have logic to disable this row and everything in it with one line...

```
tdDocs.Disabled = True;
```

Comment: I don't see why that won't work! And where have you used `disabled` in your code?

Comment: @CrakC the 'disabled="disabled"' comment comes from looking at the HTML directly after it's been rendered. It's not in the aspx page. And yes it works in IE, but not in FF or Chrome. Try it yourself!

Comment: `tdDocs.Disabled = True;` Is that javascript??

Comment: @CrakC, I said code-behind. It's C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does indeed disable all controls inside a `td` (or any container) if you set its `disabled` attribute. I didn't even know that!

But the problem is that other browsers don't. `disabled` is not a valid attribute for a `td`. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w85hztwg/), where the checkbox in the table becomes unclickable in IE, but not in the other browsers.

Solution: disable all controls individually by running a quick loop over all the controls in the td.
So instead of

```c#
tdDocs.Disabled = true;
```

write

```c#
foreach (Control ctrl in tdDocs.Controls) {
    if (ctrl is WebControl) ((WebControl)ctrl).Enabled = false;
}
```